# Query_1 OR Query_2 is not commutative, why? Query_1 OR Query_2 yields no results but Query_2 OR Query_1 does yield results

Tags: apache, solr

Query_1  yields results - number of results: 2513

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/hyrax/select?indent=on&q=(record_check_back_date_dtsi:[* TO NOW/DAY])&wt=json
```

Query_2 yields results - number of results: 4836

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/hyrax/select?indent=on&q={!join from=ora_work_id_ssi to=id}(*:* AND -file_made_available_date_tesim:[* TO *] AND file_embargo_end_date_dtsi:[* TO NOW/DAY])&wt=json
```

Query_1 or Query_2  is not yielding any results

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/hyrax/select?indent=on&q=(record_check_back_date_dtsi:[* TO NOW/DAY]) OR {!join from=ora_work_id_ssi to=id}(*:* AND -file_made_available_date_tesim:[* TO *] AND file_embargo_end_date_dtsi:[* TO NOW/DAY]) &wt=json
```

Query_2 or Query_1  yields results the same as just Q2 - number of results: 4836

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/hyrax/select?indent=on&{!join from=ora_work_id_ssi to=id}(*:* AND -file_made_available_date_tesim:[* TO *] AND file_embargo_end_date_dtsi:[* TO NOW/DAY]) OR (record_check_back_date_dtsi:[* TO NOW/DAY])&wt=json
```

Query_1  = 2513

Query_2  = 4836

Expected Total number of results for

```
(Q1 OR Q2)/(Q2 OR Q1) 
 = 2513 +  4836  = 7349
```

I have these questions:

1> Why am I not getting the Actual Total = Expected Total?

2> Why is Q1 OR Q2 not the same as Q2 OR Q1 . Isn’t this commutative?

3> Why do I get (Q1 OR Q2) = 0 results ?

4> Why do I get (Q2 OR Q1) = 4836 results  ? This means that only Q2 results are being returned and Q1 is not being run. Why?

Comment: It's hard to say when some part of your queries are escaped and some are not - they might be double escaped (some have `%20` _and_ spaces; `%20` is the escape code for a space); and since you have `[...]0` in some of them, its hard to say if that's present in your actual queries or are just something from when you copy pasted the query (and it's cutting of a `%20`, probably?); It'd be helpful if you could add an actual example of documents that doesn't get matched (I'm guessing using the join query parser might be the problem - start by debugging without the join parser)

Comment: Hi, thank you, I have copied it from one editor to another which introduced %20, please ignore, I have edited the question. Could you take a look again please?

Comment: First - negative queries need to be prefixed with `*:*` to have something to remove something from. Solr places a `*:*` in front of the query for non-complex queries, but when you introduce many clauses, it is no longer present. So just having `-file_made_available_date_tesim..` means that it doens't have anything to subtract it from, giving you an empty result. This might be one of the reasons, prepend that part of the query with `*:*`. You can also use `debug=all` to see how your query gets parsed to see any differences between the queries and find out where the generated query changes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We have tried negating from the whole (*:*) and got the same results. But for clarity of the issue we are facing, I have updated my question with your suggestion. Could you please take a look at the refined queries and questions?With the fear of my editor adding %20s, I have edited this several times. Sorry for this. Could you please refresh your page ?

Comment: I'm unable to say anything more without having examples to do proper tests with (i.e. a schema with a few fields, a few documents and a few queries with the expected results that are wrong).

Comment: Sure will get back to you soon on this.

Comment: One thing that's potentially causing a problem is the usage of a query parser at the start of the query. `q={!join ...}(blah) OR (blah)` is actually read as `q={!join ...}((blah) OR (blah))`. Try putting parentheses around the query parser: `q=({!join ...}(blah)) OR (blah)`